# how to specify repository url for composer like maven

Tags: php, composer-php

I am a beginner for **php** and I know we can specify repository in **setting.xml** about maven.
Now about **composer**, how to specify the a **repository url**.

---

I know the **composer** get lib from [github](https://www.github.com) by default, now I want to make it get lib from `artifactory.xxx.com`. I dont know how to achieve this.

---

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer that question with so few information. Composer has documentation about this topic:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md Especially look at the "VCS" and "Package" sections.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md Describes the possibilities of hosting an additional package repository.

> I know the composer get lib from github by default

That's wrong. Composer will ask the default repository located at https://packagist.org/ - and if the package is located on Github, it will be downloaded from there. But any other hosting solution is entirely possible. Also don't fall to the asumption that the Github username/reponame combo is a valid Composer package name - they are not. Composer will only use the name given inside the `composer.json` file. In short: Ignore Github as a first step, use Packagist to search for and locate packages that do what you need. The link to the correct Github repository is mentioned on Packagist.